# Нужна ли запятая или другой знак?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая или тире перед словом "обязательно"?
Скоро, Аня, станет легче (?) обязательно, а пока терпи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таком порядке слов надо ставить запятую, но тогда получается много запятых, да и прочесть предложение сложно, поэтому лучше переставить наречие:

*Скоро, Аня, станет **обязАтельно** легче, а пока терпИ.*

Comment: "При таком порядке слов" лучше интонационное тире.

Comment: Где его поставить? Запишите предложение с тире и объясните постановку знаков.  Контекст  также надо учитывать, что до этого было сказано? По порядку слов можно предположить мысль о том, что легче не станет.

Comment: Перед "обязательно". Думаю, это лучший вариант. Это слово интонационно подчёркивается, чтобы успокоить человека.

Comment: Записываю:  (1) Скоро, Аня, станет легче – обязательно, // а пока терпи.   (2) Скоро, Аня, станет легче –  // обязательно, а пока терпи.    Как читать-то?

Comment: Не понимаю, в чём разница.

Comment: Не понимаете, так послушайте...  Варианты различаются основной паузой, а это деление предложения на разные фразы, описание двух разных ситуаций.

Comment: Ну понятно, что от тире пауза будет больше. Тогда (2).

Comment: А я бы не делил на ситуации, это разговорный стиль, а не высокохудожественный. Здесь слова возникают неожиданно.

Comment: В устной речи слова возникают всегда правильно, согласно ситуации. Мы же носители, у нас интуиция. А вот правильно записать не всегда получается. Также контекст продумайте - он отражается на структуре предложения, как мне кажется. Пока, пока...  А то в чат выгонят.

Comment: До чата ещё далеко. *В устной речи слова возникают всегда правильно* — вы серьёзно? Вспомните "упорно не могу". Да и часто можно услышать такое: *вот подумай, что ты только что сморозил*.

Comment: "Правильно - многозначное слово, здесь я имею в виду - соответственно. Каков человек - такова и речь. И про чат. Вы говорите - автоматика, а почему туда модератор направляет? Красный сигнал?

Comment: Если количество комментариев набирает определённое число, то положено перемещать их в чат. Можно посчитать: насчитал 20. Могу сказать, что на это также влияют удалённые комментарии: как-то проводил эксперимент и много раз переотправлял комментарий, удаляя предыдущий, а потом модератор перенёс в чат лишь несколько комментариев. Считал ли он их количество? Это вряд ли.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, а переставлять ничего никуда не надо. Предложение нормальное: естественная, живая речь.

Comment: Естественное предложение? А давайте посмотрим:  «Скоро, Аня, станет легче, обязательно, а пока терпи».  Красиво? Удобно читается? Мне кажется, что нет. Четыре запятые подряд,  и все на разном основании.  Куда наречие относится – сразу и не разберешь.

Comment: Красиво — ибо естественно и по-человечески. Очень удобно читается тем, кто настроен видеть за словами человека и интонацию, а не грамматику. «Мне кажется, что нет». — Это вам кажется :) Лично я мгновенно понял, «куда наречие относится» — может быть, потому, что без необходимости никогда не занимаюсь выяснением таких вопросов. Знаете анекдот про сороконожку?

Comment: Откуда мне знать (про сороконожку).  Первое, что мне бросилось в глаза - это неестественный порядок слов для такого предложения, а отсюда все остальные выводы.  Наречие нужно обособлять. Вы вот правильно прочитаете, кто-то неправильно, а мне не правится неоднозначность прочтения, мне это кажется некрасивым.  Стилистический недочет, однако, если не брать в расчет разное понимание красоты.

Comment: Для живой речи и реальной ситуации такой порядок слов совершенно естественен. Повторяю: кто за человеческими словами ощущает произносящего их, с теми «неоднозначность прочтения» не приключается на каждом шагу. «Стилистический недочет, однако» — Я не думаю, что живая речь всерьёз нуждается в стилистических дочётах. Анекдот про сороконожку могу рассказать.

Comment: Неприличный, наверное?  Я пока  только детские стихи знаю: «У сороконожки народились крошки..."  Давайте  уж лучше анекдот, а то я философию (именное в русском языке) не очень люблю…

Comment: Нет, анекдот совершенно нормальный, даже... хотел написать «детский», но вовремя вспомнил, что детские анекдоты и есть самые неприличные. «Даже невинный» — вот! И даже философский! Короче, анекдот: у сороконожки спросили: «А как ты ходишь? Сначала становишься на каждую, скажем, пятую ножку с одной стороны, потом переступаешь на каждую пятую с другой стороны, потом с первой стороны переступаешь на каждую... какую?» Сороконожка задумалась — и разучилась ходить!

Comment: Да,  вроде слышала.  Только это ваш портрет, а не мой.   Вы мне такие же вопросы задаете, так что как бы мне  "ходить" не разучиться.  Вот недавний пример – про кукурузу.

Comment: Нет, Sharon, я «ходить» не разучусь — именно потому, что не задумываюсь над ненужными вопросами. И потому, что умею отличать их от нужных :)

Comment: Ну да, это, конечно, повод для оптимизма. ;)

Comment: Это повод для моего оптимизма — а способны ли радоваться за ближнего вы, судить вам :)